# How to extract email address from a string using perl?

Tags: regex, perl, email

How to extract emails address from a string using perl and to put the email addres into a variable?
My strings looks like

```
Ben Tailor <bentaylor@gmail.com>
barbara@gmail.com, barbara2@gmail.com, Ben Tailor <bentaylor@gmail.com>
```

I tryed this

```
$string ="Ben Tailor <bentaylor@gmail.com>";
$string =~ /\b([^\s]+@[^\s]+)\b/g ;
print $string;
```

And the Out put xas:

```
Ben Tailor <bentaylor@gmail.com>
```

Someone have an Idea?

Fixed using

```
Email::Valid->address($string);
```

Thx

Comment: It would output the same as the input string because all you did was perform a regex match against it then output the string again. You didn't use the captured part $1 or substitue replace s///g;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Valid.  It seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at Email::Address or Email::AddressParser from cpan

```
 my @addrs = Email::Address->parse(
    q[me@local, Tony <me@local>, "Tony" <me@local>]
  );
```

This returns a list of Email::Address objects it finds in the input string.