# Get email from string

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to extract email address from a string using perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276309/how-to-extract-email-address-from-a-string-using-perl)

Say I have a string like this:

> Dr. X University of School name in nowhere pete@school.edu Blah blah 3 one niner

How would I get the email out of there?

Comment: Nope, not an exact duplicate. This is to extract email addresses from free flowing text.

Comment: If that's your problem, you definitely should not use a regex with `[A-Z]` and not a insensitive case flag.

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Email::Find](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Email%3a%3aFind).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use YAML;
use Email::Find;

my $finder = Email::Find->new(\&print_email);

while ( my $data = <DATA> ) {
    $finder->find(\$data);
}

sub print_email {
    print Dump \@_;
}

__DATA__
Say I have a string like this:

Dr. X University of School name in nowhere pete@school.edu Blah blah 3 one niner

How would I get the email out of there?
```

Output:

```
---
- !!perl/array:Mail::Address
  - ''
  - pete@school.edu
- pete@school.edu
```

Answer (score -2):

You do not say the language but you could use this method:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/extractemail.aspx
http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=200875

and there were many others on Google (no offense, just what I saw for helping you.)